# How to add flutter SDK to PATH permanently on ubuntu linux?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, flutter, terminal, path

I'm very new to using linux as my primary OS. Yesterday I just did a clean install of ubuntu on my pc. I after that I started setting up my desktop. Anything necessary is being installed to run flutter but whenever I run `flutter` `flutter: command not found`. I have tried seeing similar questions on stackoverflow but I do not see specific configuration of adding flutter to PATH on ubuntu and it is kinda confusing to me since I'm not experienced with linux for now.

When I enter the following `export PATH="$PATH:development/flutter/bin"` command in the terminal, flutter is working but when I close that terminal in which I entered this command and boom, flutter is not being recognized in the console again.

What I want is flutter sdk to be added permanently to PATH so that I can access `flutter` command whenever I want in the terminal.

I'm using ubuntu `-v Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS`.
Thank you.

Comment: check `~/.profile`

Comment: Yes, I've just checked it now with nano.

Comment: sure, your welcome

Comment: No it did not solve my problem. Do you mind adding and answer bro. This looks like Chinese to me inside the `.profile`.

Comment: see https://www.stefaanlippens.net/bashrc_and_others/ and/or https://www.tecmint.com/understanding-shell-initialization-files-and-user-profiles-linux/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just edit the .bashrc file in your home directory and add

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/[path to the directory you have installed flutter]/flutter/bin"
```

For example:

```
`export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/Documents/development/flutter/bin"`
```

Save the file and reopen the terminal

Comment: Hi, you should format your answer. It'd look more nice.

Comment: this must be the accepted answer
because the official docs doesn't include the $HOME variable

Answer (score 8):

1. **Modify your .bashrc file (a file that configures your bash shells)**

Go to your home folder and press Ctrl+H, to see hidden files. And open the .bashrc file.

Or, alternatively, put this in a terminal:

```
sudo gedit ~/.bashrc
```

**2. Add a directory to your PATH variable (a global variable which tells your computer where to look for programs)**

The *last line* of your .bashrc file should look something like this*:

```
export PATH="/home/tom/Flutter/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin:${PATH}"
```

*If you want to add multiple new folders to your PATH variable, feel free to repeat this line as often as you'd like.

3. **Re-open a terminal**

After you modify your path variable you should re-open your terminals.

Comment: `# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
fi
export PATH="/home/james/development/flutter/bin:${PATH}"`

Comment: @TomO it does not work for me i am currently on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Comment: I have modified my answer. It should now work on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS.

Answer (score 3):

Some of you you may struggle to this problem for long time since the above answers may confuse you.
Well!
I have tried those to, but a trick is some linux not have another rc file, hence instead of `~/.bashrc`, find `~/.zshrc` and then add `~/flutter/bin` to the last line of file as follows

```
export PATH="$PATH:~/flutter/bin"
```

Then open terminal and run

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

After that run flutter and it will work

```
flutter
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you refresh your **.bashrc** file by running

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

then verifies that the flutter command is available.

```
which flutter
```

Answer (score 0):

path is located at Environment at /etc folder,
To edit ,

```
sudo gedit /etc/environment
```

after edit
MUST::::: **restart** computer

Answer (score 0):

I would keep your .bashrc clean and not touch it.   Use .bash_aliases for any export paths you need to add.  This way you can easily see the exports you have added and where they are pointing to:
IE.
nano .bash_aliases

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk
export ANDROID_USER_HOME=$HOME/.android/

export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:/snap/bin/flutter
```

after saving.   Just close all your terminal windows and reopen them.

Answer (score -1):

the chosen answer is completely correct but needs step by step description and didn't mentioned about connect android studio to flutter

To add Flutter to your Linux path permanently, you need to modify your shell's configuration file to include the Flutter SDK's `bin` directory in your `PATH` environment variable. The process varies slightly depending on the shell you are using (e.g., Bash, Zsh, Fish, etc.). Here's a general guide for adding Flutter to your path using Bash, which is the most common shell on Linux:

1. **Open your shell's configuration file**:

   - If you're using Bash, the configuration file is `~/.bashrc`.
   - For Zsh, it's `~/.zshrc`.
   - For Fish, it's `~/.config/fish/config.fish`.
   - For Csh or Tcsh, it's `~/.cshrc` or `~/.tcshrc`.
2. **Add Flutter to your PATH**:

   - Open the configuration file in a text editor. For example, if you're using Bash, you can open the terminal and type:

     ```bash
     nano ~/.bashrc
     ```
   - Add the following line at the end of the file, replacing `[PATH_TO_FLUTTER_SDK_DIRECTORY]` with the actual path to your Flutter SDK directory:

     ```bash
     export PATH="$PATH:[PATH_TO_FLUTTER_SDK_DIRECTORY]/flutter/bin"
     ```

     For example, if your Flutter SDK is located in `/home/yourusername/development/flutter`, the line would be:

     ```bash
     export PATH="$PATH:/home/yourusername/development/flutter/bin"
     ```
3. **Save and close the file**:

   - If you're using `nano`, press `Ctrl + O` to save the changes, then `Ctrl + X` to exit.
4. **Apply the changes**:

   - For the changes to take effect, you need to reload your shell's configuration file. You can do this by closing and reopening your terminal or by sourcing the configuration file. For Bash, you can use:

     ```bash
     source ~/.bashrc
     ```
5. **Verify the installation**:

   - To ensure that Flutter has been successfully added to your path, you can run:

     ```bash
     echo $PATH
     ```
   - This command should output your `PATH` environment variable, and you should see the path to the Flutter SDK's `bin` directory included.
6. **Test Flutter**:

   - Finally, you can test if Flutter is correctly installed and accessible by running:

     ```bash
     flutter doctor
     ```
   - This command checks your environment and displays a report to the terminal window.

Remember, the exact steps might vary slightly depending on your Linux distribution and the shell you are using. The provided steps are a general guide and should work for most setups.

## Android Studio

To resolve the "Unable to determine Android Studio version" and "Unable to find bundled Java version" issues on Ubuntu, follow these steps:

1. **Locate Android Studio Path**: First, you need to find where Android Studio is installed on your system. You can do this by running `flutter doctor -v` in your terminal. Look for the Android Studio section in the output to find its installation path.
2. **Locate Java in Android Studio Directory**: Once you have the Android Studio path, navigate to the directory where Android Studio is installed. Inside the Android Studio directory, you should find a `jbr` folder instead of the traditional `jre` folder. This is because newer versions of Android Studio use `jbr` (JetBrains Runtime) instead of `jre` (Java Runtime Environment) [5].
3. **Create a Symbolic Link**: To resolve the issue, you need to create a symbolic link from `jbr` to `jre` within the Android Studio directory. This can be done by running the following command in your terminal, replacing `[PATH_TO_ANDROID_STUDIO]` with the actual path to your Android Studio installation:

   ```bash
   cd [PATH_TO_ANDROID_STUDIO]
   sudo ln -s jbr jre
   ```

   This command creates a symbolic link named `jre` that points to the `jbr` directory, effectively making the bundled Java version accessible to Flutter.
4. **Verify the Fix**: After creating the symbolic link, run `flutter doctor` again to check if the issue has been resolved. If everything is set up correctly, you should no longer see the "Unable to find bundled Java version" error.
5. **Restart Your System**: In some cases, you might need to restart your system for the changes to take effect fully. This ensures that all environment variables and paths are correctly updated .

This solution addresses the issue by making the bundled Java version accessible to Flutter by creating a symbolic link. It's a workaround that has been reported to work for users facing similar issues on Ubuntu.