# Edit PATH permanently on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, flutter, terminal, path, ubuntu-16.04

While trying to add Flutter to PATH in Ubuntu , I messed up and now PATH variable is this:

```
/home/adish/bin:/home/adish/.local/bin:/home/adish/bin:/home/adish/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:~/Flutter/flutter/bin
```

Now , I am trying to remove all duplicates as well as "~/Flutter/flutter/bin" from PATH. But it revert back when i restart terminal.

What should I do? 
And is there a better way to add Flutter to PATH?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60146386/9142279 might help

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit the environment file which is located here `/etc/environment`

1. copy your current environment file in a .bak file :

`sudo cp /etc/environment /etc/environment.bak`

2. edit the environment file using nano ide :

`sudo nano /etc/environment`

3. then add the correct path knowing that paths are delimited by `:`